# MongoDB: Get pageable list of referenced objects which matches a condition?

Tags: java, mongodb, repository

Java + Spring Boot + MongoDB Repositories (+Custom repositories)

I have following schema:

**Event**

```
"date" : "2016-04-01T16:00", 
"name" : "xyz", 
"place" : DBRef("place", ObjectId("xyz"))
```

**EventOccurrence**

```
"siteName" : "", 
"url" : "", 
"creationDate" : "", 
"lastUpdated" : "", 
"data" : {
    "kategorie" : "music"
}, 
"event" : DBRef("event", ObjectId("zxy"))
```

My goal is to get all Events (pageable), which are referenced by an eventOccurrence which has an nested Attribute "data.kategorie" which matches a regex "XY".

I am trying to create a custom repository method to get this data, but it does not work till now :(

Till now I only find out how to get all EventOccurrences with the condition with following DB shell query: `db.eventOccurrence.find({"data.kategorie": {'$regex': 'xy'}})`

Is my goal possible anyway?

In need something like `db.eventOccurrence.find({"event.$ref":{ "data.kategorie": {'$regex': 'xy'}}})`

Thank you very much!

Comment: I did some progress with following query `db.eventOccurrence.find({"data.kategorie": {'$regex': 'Film'}}, {event:1,_id:0})`. Now I am getting a List of event References. My Question is how can I expose those Objects?